# Weird CSS image hover

Tags: css, sass

I'm creating a hover effect on an image with SCSS on a WordPress site (see gif: https://gyazo.com/1a35247e40d74b5fc756d508de4231eb)

As you see the image gets a "distorted" after hovering over it, maybe the `ease-in` property is wrong, or I'm not doing the hover effect properly. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong in the code when it behaves like this.

This is the code that is working:

(left out some SCSS because it was so wast but the `&` is used to use parent class)

Edit: The HTML & SCSS

```
<div class="project_container">
    <div class="project_content">
      Test event
      <br>
      2018
    </div>
    <img src="http://testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/img.jpg" class="attachment-full aligncenter">
</div>
```

-

```
&_container {
position: relative;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;

&:hover {
  & > img {
    opacity: .2;
  }

  & > .project_content {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

& img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /*
  object-fit: none;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  */

  // Hover tranisiton
  transition: opacity .5s;
 }
}


&_content {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .5s;

// Center Position
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

 color: $purple;
 z-index: 2;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: center;
 }
}
```

So using `:hover;` on the `&_container` gives the `project_content`: `opacity: 1;`. Then it also blurs the background image with the `opacity: .2;`, and the effect is achieved with a `transition;`

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the related HTML also

Comment: I'm not seeing any "distortion"...please provide a functional demo AND clarify exactly what the issue is.

Comment: It looks like you're using an image that's at a higher resolution than what's being rendered out. The distortion looks like the browser downsampling it. Resize your image to the exact dimension you need to avoid this.

Comment: @Paulie_D now the HTML is there

Comment: @André Dion Ahh maybe that's the problem, I used quite a large img size to test the `object-fit`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote everything with the hover effect so now I use an overlay class which has `opacity: 0;` on it (and a transition that takes care of the effect on `:hover`)

This is a simple version of the HTML:

```
<div class="project_container">
  <div class="project_content">
   <p>Content</p> 
  </div>
  <img src="#" alt="test">
  <div class="project_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and the simplified SCSS:

```
.project {
 &_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;

  &:hover .project_overlay,
  &:hover .project_content {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .5s;
  }
 }

 & img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 &_overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
 }
}
```